# php allow secure connection from other server

Tags: php, remote-server

I have a hosted server that is unable to run cronjobs. Now on that server there is a file I can only run from that server due to the limited dbase acces so I cannot copy the file to another server.

Now I have another PHP web server with full access and the possibility to run cronjobs from. I intend to run a cronjob on that server that calls the script on the hosted server. Cronjob may look like: wget -O /dev/null http://myserver.com/thescript.php

I think this will work well except the script on the hosted server is secured behind a login page and 2FA. I have access to that script and I am thinking of building an if else in the beginning of that page that can bypass the login and 2FA if the remote server IP is x.x.x.x
Is this a 'secure' way and if so what to take into account when building this?

The hosted script has the following code to check login access at the beginning of each file:

`<?php // Initialize the session session_start(); // Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true || $_SESSION["smok"] !== true){ header("location: index.php"); exit; } ?>`

Comment: Question: Why not just move everything to the better server which supports cron?

Comment: `Is this a 'secure' way`...well, well the IP address may not be 100% reliable, necessarily (see note about `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124184/is-it-possible-to-send-http-packet-via-spoofed-ip). It shouldn't be possible to spoof the server's firewall though, AFAIK.

Comment: A lot of server to server interactions are secured by a secret key known only to the calling script (make sure you send all requests via HTTPS of course). A common standard version of that is OAuth2 with a server->server flow using secret client credentials rather than interactive password authentication. And/or there's specific certificate authentication on that connection only (so the server expects the client to present a particular security certificate known only to that client). IP restrictions at the firewall level could possibly be added on top of that.

Comment: Does that particular script need to run _outside_ of the cron context as well? If not, then I'd say protecting it via 2FA makes rather little sense to begin with. I'd rather go for HTTP Auth then (perhaps `digest` instead of `basic`), via an HTTPS connection that should probably be "secure enough" then.

Comment: @ADyson there is still a contract with the hosting provider till march next year.

Comment: @James That doesn't stop you moving everything to your other server, which presumably you've already paid for anyway. So it shouldn't really cost you any _extra_ money, assuming the server has capacity to host the migrated stuff as well. Just something to think about

Comment: But in your current scenario, in the simplest case, have a complex secret key which only the "other" server has stored (securely, on its disk somewhere). Make the requesting script put that value into a header in the HTTP request when it sends it to the hosted server, and then the hosted server can check if that header value is present and correct before it allows access to the data (in cases where the regular authentication also isn't present). This is comparatively crude, but depending on the level of security you need to have, it might do the job for a short-term fix.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the important thing for you is to run the script on the hosted server.
I'd say these two ways will solve the issue:

1. you can create a php file with an endless loop in it, on the hosted server, which will run the actual script only than when you want it. Like looking for the hours etc... (I wouldn't recommend this though, for one thing it relies on having a browser window open all the time to respond to that header and refresh it.)
2. you have for sure a SSH access on your hosted server. Your "good" server could have a cron job which can connect via SSH to your hosted server and run the script. This way, authentication of the connection is provided by SSH itself and the PHP script doesn't need to worry about it. Just ensure the script can only be executed via the terminal on the server, and not via HTTP.